# how to play .gif files in android

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an app using html5 and java script and can convert into android app using phonegap. i have several gif files in my app. unfortunately those are not working any more i.e only static images are displayed i want to play the images?

Comment: VENKI, how you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can play gif with the help of this tutorial

http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Comment: sorry to say i am not using any android(java) code at all jut is and html5 and java script i am using phone gap software to convert it into android application

Comment: oh means all you are viewing in web format from the application ??

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, although animated gif support was supposedly added in Froyo (2.2), it is turned off on most phones (for some reason it's an optional setting)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

Even worse, I think it is always off in the web view used by PhoneGap.

I have had to find workarounds for things I was doing with animated gifs on Android PhoneGap. I had an animated gif as a loading spinner in iOS and had to use an animated Canvas instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found a great solution, I use Spritely plugin:
http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-sprite-animation/
Now I can use a png sprite instead of gifs, wich is cool because I can use antialiasing and transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, how i fixed it was by creating the gifs from videos in photoshop extracting the layers individually, saving them for web as a gif then importing them into e www/img folder in the assets of the phone gap project. Calling them directly from the img folder   they play both in Web and Android 4.4 KitKat with a google nexus 4 , Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS based animation:
http://cssload.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My solution, no, workaround, is to use video. Sounds crazy, but works. I convert GIFs in mp4-movies (and ogg) and use the html5 video tag to display them.

But you'll encounter some new problems with video: On Adroid 2.* the video will be played in an external viewer, usually in full screen mode. 
From Android 4 on it will be displayed embedded, but may stretched to on or the other side. width an height only work if use in style sheets. But this may lead to far of topic.